# Liferay can't get request parameter from renderrequest

Tags: parameters, request, liferay

so here is my problem:
I have an actionrequest which handles a button click. So it should redirect to another page. We have a Url generator which works well and puts the desired parameters in the url, like:

```
parametersNameValue.put("foo", "asdfgh");
```

The problem comes in the doView of the redirected page:

```
 String foo = ParamUtil.getString(renderRequest, "foo", null);
```

and foo becomes null. I can clearly see the foo parameter in the url with the correct value. I tried many other tricks like:

```
HttpServletRequest request = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(renderRequest);
    String foo = request.getParameter("foo");
```

or writing the whole portletnamespace before the foo (as it is in the namespace), tried getting it with renderRequest.getParameter("foo"), but still nothing. And the thing is that this code works in our test and production servers, but not on our local development machines. I did see a lot of similar questions, but none of them helped me (most of the answers are to use ParamUtil, which is already being used). And all the other pages work this way and there is no problem.

Comment: Which version of liferay? In any case the missing part is the portlet names pace in parameter name.

Comment: @DanieleBaggio Liferay 6.1 CE

Comment: The frontend is made with jsp?

Answer (score 0):

after two days of debugging I found the solution. The problem was that when generating the url we have:

```
    List<String> portletList = layoutTypePortlet.getPortletIds();
    String portletNamespace = !portletList.isEmpty() ? portletList.get(0) :     "";
```

2 empty portplets were placed before the original portlet, so the portletList had 3 elements and the one we needed was the 3rd. So after removing them, it started working.